# v8::Value::ToString': no overloaded function takes 0 arguments

Tags: c++, node.js, npm

I've been trying to npm install this node package module here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dll-injector/v/0.2.3

Which is a bit old but still the code inside is valuable to me. Every time I try to install it with `npm install node-dll-injector`; I get errors. More specifically within the cpp core file of the package module.

its not building because: `v8::Value::ToString': no overloaded function takes 0 arguments`
The line of code with the issue: `String::Utf8Value arg0(info[0]->ToString());`

I believe it has something to do with outdated node version? I need a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's a newer version of engine itself causes those errors. No parameter versions of those getters were deprecated and  apparently were finally dropped for technical reasons ( see [code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v10.16.3/deps/v8/include/v8.h#L2454) ), but some online sources still list them as viable.

Comment: What would be the best approach to refactor this code? I just need to replace the "ToString" Correct?

Comment: @HabibAina it have to be called with appropriate context as argument